# Codeigniter framework: File upload bug name for Thai language

Tags: php, codeigniter

## Use Codeigniter class file upload for save file#***

**- File name (Example Document.pdf)**
After upload new file name is (Example_Document.pdf) but return file name is Example Document.pdf, I need file name = Example Document.pdf and return file name = Example Document.pdf

---

**- File name (ตัวอย่าง เอกสาร.pdf)**
After upload new file is (à¸•à¸±à¸§à¸­à¸¢à¹ˆà¸²à¸‡_à¹€à¸­à¸à¸ªà¸²à¸£.pdf) but return file name = ตัวอย่าง เอกสาร.pdf, I need file name = ตัวอย่าง เอกสาร.pdf and return file name = ตัวอย่าง เอกสาร.pdf
How to fix this bug?***

```php
function do_upload($field = "")
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = "/upload/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = false;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $file_name = "";
        if ( $this->upload->do_upload($field)) {
            $file_name = $this->upload->data("file_name");
        }
        return $file_name;
    }
```

Comment: seems like utf-8 conversion issue.Not too sure as i am new to codeigniter

Comment: have you tried `$file_name = utf8_decode($file_name);` already?

Comment: Unsuccessful, do you have example?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want underscores (I think using underscore is way better) you can do this:

```
$config['remove_spaces'] = false;
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html#preferences

Comment: Then to upload Thai language file, Do you have any ideas.

Comment: Say you want to make language file for the upload library. You put a file in `application/language/thai/upload_lang.php` you can follow the required terms via `system/language/english/upload_lang.php` your Thai version will override it. Then in `application/config/config.php` you change language to `thai` or you can follow allong with: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#sample-language-files

Comment: Did my answer address your question however?

Comment: Might be of some interest to you: https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter3-translations/tree/develop/language/thai. Again you would do the same thing. Put the thai folder in the `application/language/` and configure to use that language.